# How Can I Always Display A Particular Post First Using WP_Query?

Tags: posts, database, wp-query, customization, query

My apologies if this question has already been asked somewhere else, I searched but couldn't find anything. I am working on a tours website, there will be individual package pages that show some text, images and some other stuff.

On the right hand side of my single package pages I have a comparison table which is merely a custom WP_Query pulling out all packages from the database using the following code:

```
// Package fetching arguments
$pargs = array(
    "numberposts" => -1,
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "post_type" => "packages",
);

// Get out packages
$cpackages = new WP_Query($pargs);
```

I however would like the first item of this comparison table to be the current package the visitor is viewing. Say for example the user is viewing a package called "Tour A" on the right hand side I would like to pull out all packages but make sure that Tour A is at the beginning and highlighted then the other posts displayed.

I've looked into sticky posts, but they don't really apply to what I am wanting to do, because if someone is on Tour B, then it needs to be displayed first in the comparison table and then so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the `$cpackages` results twice, and `rewind_posts()` in between. first time only output when the id matches the current post id, then skip that id the second time through.

Comment: Nice solution brotato. Works perfectly! thank you.